# How to bind to the 'Master' row in a DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this piece of XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    x:Name="Window"
    >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Master}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="MasterField1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={????}, Path=MasterField1}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="DetailsField1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Field1}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="DetailsField2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Field2}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

With these two classes:

```
public class Master
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string MasterField1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string MasterID { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now what i want to accomplish is in the RowDetailsTemplate i want to show the current MasterField1, but how should i do the Binding for this to work?? So how should i do the:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="MasterField1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={????}, Path=MasterField1}" />
```

in order to have the MasterField1 shown??

Thanks

---

## Found the solution

I can do it like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="MasterField1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=DataContext.MasterField1}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a Master property on the Detail class? You can also set it when you set the Id:

```
public class Detail
{
    private string _masterID;
    public string MasterID { 
        get {
            return _masterI;
        }
        set {
            _masterID = value;
            Master = FindMasterById(value);
        }
    }
    public Master Master { get ; set ; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then just do the binding:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="MasterField1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Master.MasterField1}" />
```

Comment: Yes that would be one solution, but i don't want to do that. The example is not representative to what i want. What i really want to know is how to do the binding in XAML, so for example if i would like to display the number of Details for that Master i could bind to : 
    <GridViewColumn Header="Nr of Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Details.Count}" >

Comment: But you can still do that with this approach: <GridViewColumn Header="MasterField1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Master.Details.Count}" />

Comment: True (i was realyzing that when i typed my answer), but i my case i don't have access to the sources of the implementation of the Master/Detail classes. So i have to do it without changing them.

Comment: I've found the solution. I've edited my question with the answer at the bottom.
Thanks